# Кодировка адреса отправления в функции mail

Tags: email, php

Столкнулся с проблемой отправки писем функцией php mail на одном из хостингов.
Суть вкратце: есть хостинг с сайтом на UMI, также в качестве форума там поставлен phpbb 3.
В обоих скриптах почта через функцию mail не работает, с umi получить полную  трассировку не получилось, а в phpbb были утсановлено, что скрипт в поле to: ставит: =?utf-8?BGD0L?=, после чего почта не отправляется, пробывал ставить костыль в виде прописывания "to:" не в закодированном виде - все отправляется, тоже самое в umi.

Тут же возникает вопрос, почему в нативном виде это не работает на этом хостинге, т.к. сами скрипты umi и phpbb никак не изменялись до этого, след все должно работать и так.

Update: Получил логи send mail(ip и домен заменены):

```
May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14026]: q4R20pjs014026: Authentication-Warning: 89-25-135-105.ovz.vps.reg.ru: admin set sender to 208312@mail.ru using -f
 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14026]: q4R20pjs014026: from=admin_site@mail.ru, size=1345, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<51db5237a86bf04aaac0819d462dc456@www.my_site.ru>, relay=admin@localhost

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14026]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14026]: q4R20pjs014026: to==?UTF-8?B?YmF0cG9wcGVzdHk=?= <grizan4745283@mail.ru>, ctladdr=admin_site@mail.ru (500/503), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31345, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q4R20psA014027 Message accepted for delivery)

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14030]: q4R20pul014030: Authentication-Warning: 89-25-135-105.ovz.vps.reg.ru: admin set sender to admin_site@mail.ru using -f

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14030]: q4R20pul014030: from=admin_site@mail.ru, size=1258, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<ee81cea8a43e46354b4b439195567701@www.my_site.ru>, relay=admin@localhost

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14031]: STARTTLS=server, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NO, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14030]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256

 May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14031]: q4R20pe3014031: from=<admin_site@mail.ru>, size=1467, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<ee81cea8a43e46354b4b439195567701@www.my_site.ru>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]

May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14030]: q4R20pul014030: to==?UTF-8?B?YWRtaW4=?= <my_site@mail.ru>, ctladdr=admin_site@mail.ru (500/503), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31258, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q4R20pe3014031 Message accepted for delivery)

May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14029]: q4R20psA014027: to=<grizan4745283@mail.ru>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=121554, relay=mxs.mail.ru. [94.100.176.20], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable

May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14029]: q4R20psA014027: q4R20ps9014029: DSN: Service unavailable

May 27 06:00:51 89-25-135-105 sendmail[14029]: q4R20ps9014029: to=<admin_site@mail.ru>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=32861, relay=mxs.mail.ru. [94.100.176.20], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK id=1SYSmp-0001Nm-BM)
```

Comment: @w00lf, уточните, плз, 

1) раньше все работало, а потом перестало ?

2) поле `to:` это в заголовках письма, или `RCPT TO:` из ESMTP протокола ?

Comment: Да, раньше по словам клиента все работало, хотя я не могу сказать точно. Поле "to:" в данном случает относится к 1-му параметру функции mail('to', 'subject',....), т.к. оба приложения работают через него. В phpbb например в этот параметр ставится: 

'=?utf-8?' . base64_encode('целевой мейл куда нужно отправить') . '?='

В итоге в функцию передается: mail('=?utf-8?BGD0L?=', 'subject', ....)

Comment: И что дальше ? 

Письмо лежит в очереди, потом (через пару дней) приходит сообщение от `MAILER DAEMON` *не могу доставить, permanent error ...* ?

Comment: В том то и дело, что сообщений об ошибках не приходит, просто молча прогоняется скрипт а письма не приходят.

Comment: А вот это странно, надо бы логи MTA (smtp mail server) посмотреть. Не думаю, что nslookup (type=MX) для такого адреса какой-то домен вернет. Скорее всего в адресе отправителя такое же. Тогда письмо должно попасть на postmaster@local.domain. Но он (зараза) их может просто выбрасывать, конечно.

Но, это все по месту смотреть надо. 

В любом случае, если раньше письма в таком виде уходили, то в сервере был какой-то фильтр, преобразующий адреса, а потом его удалили. 

Кстати, что за сервер (mail server) ?

Comment: На счет сервера надо уточнить у хостера, сейчас к сожелнию не могу это сделать, т.к. не на работе, на счет того, что письма раньше уходили как раз не известно, мне не уточняли на счет этого. 
Не посоветуешь какими командами можно прошарить эту информацию - на счет типа сервера?

Comment: Я использовал в основном grep  и vi для логов в /var/log/... из под root.

Comment: Т.е. по логам можно определить тип сервера почты? Кстати на счет того, что там мог быть настроен фильтр для такого рода сообщений- это маловероятно, т.к. никаких манипуляций с мейлерами приложения насколько я знаю не производилось, след по идее все должно работать из коробки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то из приведенного протокола я вижу, что **=?utf-8?BGD0L?=** тут ни при чем.

Смотрите (это первый релей внутри):

***q4R20pjs014026***: to==?UTF-8?B?YmF0cG9wcGVzdHk=?= [klzzwxh:0001rizan4745283@mail.ru](mailto:klzzwxh:0001rizan4745283@mail.ru), ctladdr=admin_site@mail.ru (500/503), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31345, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (***q4R20psA014027*** Message accepted for delivery)

Просто нет адреса **[klzzwxh:0005rizan4745283@mail.ru](mailto:klzzwxh:0005rizan4745283@mail.ru)**

Сообщение об этом успешно отослано на:

to= [klzzwxh:0008dmin_site@mail.ru](mailto:klzzwxh:0008dmin_site@mail.ru), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=32861, relay=mxs.mail.ru. [94.100.176.20], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK id=1SYSmp-0001Nm-BM)

Это следует из

***q4R20psA014027***: to=[klzzwxh:0010rizan4745283@mail.ru](mailto:klzzwxh:0010rizan4745283@mail.ru), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=121554, relay=mxs.mail.ru. [94.100.176.20], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable

(бэкслэш перед адресами вынуждено поставил я из-за *особенностей* данного редактора (наверняка регэкспами программировали))

Comment: Из за чего тогда эти сообщения могут не отправляться? Как я понимаю, необходимо поменять сами настройки send mail на хостинге?
Поспрашивал на счет этой проблемы, говорят, что у umi часто бывают такие косяки с отправлением почты.
   ps: relay при удачном отправлении должно содержать адрес почтового домена куда отправляется письмо?

Comment: Не знаю. 

Как человек, писавший один из MTA, могу сказать, что всякие добавки к каноническому адресу в протоколе (пусть даже они MUST в RFC) решительно не одобряю. 

*Канонический адрес в ascii - и все будет доходить.*

Вот здесь (на форуме), например, grizan4745283@mail.ru в ответе превращается (**кем/чем ?**) в какую-то фигню. В почте на ее пути от источника до почтового клиента часто то же самое.

Comment: Ок, спасибо за разьяснения, буду искать дальше в чем тут может быть дело.